# User defined attributes for serialization in c++ is possibile?

Tags: c++, attributes

I'm wondering if it's possible to use custom attributes for serialization, like in c# or C++/CTR. This can save a lot of time creating classes with serialization and de-serialization and dealing with padding.

Example from CRT:

```
[System::Serializable]
struct SomeStruct{
    int Number = 10;
    bool Flag = false;
    float OneAndHaf = 1.5f;
};
```

What I want to finish with is something like this:

```
[[Serialize]]
struct SomeStruct{
    int Number = 10;
    bool Flag = false;
    [[Serialize::Ignore]]//and maybe some extra stuff 
    float OneAndHaf = 1.5f;
};
```

Comment: You basically want static reflexion which is not officially supported in the language as for now.

Comment: yup and i got idea generate serialize function with external tool and use library [link](https://github.com/foonathan/cppast) or write my own parsing tool and use attribute 
with dummy macro to tag it